# ODBC SQL - ROUND in HAVING clause is invalid

Tags: sql, excel, subquery, odbc, having

I have the following command that I use to extract data through ODBC:

```
SELECT SALES_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF, SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE
FROM SALES_LEDGER
INNER JOIN AUDIT_SPLIT ON SALES_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF = AUDIT_SPLIT.ACCOUNT_REF
GROUP BY
SALES_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF, SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE
HAVING
ROUND(SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT), 2) <> SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE;
```

Running this in Excel without the ROUND is fine but I need the ROUND because otherwise the values of the SUM are not equal to BALANCE and I get false results.

The error in Excel is:
"ODBC: ERROR [42000] Syntax error: Invalid filter in HAVING clause"

Why can't I have the ROUND command there? I try with CAST as well but it is the ROUND that I really need there.

Comment: You could try something like `HAVING SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT) < SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE - 0.01 OR  SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT) > SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE + 0.01`

Comment: @jarlh Thank you, I tried it. Adding this gives the error "ODBC: ERROR [42000] Syntax error: Invalid condition"
Adding parentheses like this 
(SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT) < SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE - 0.01) OR  (SUM(AUDIT_SPLIT.GROSS_AMOUNT) > SALES_LEDGER.BALANCE + 0.01)
Results in:
"ODBC: ERROR [42000] Syntax error: Expression cannot contain mixture of aggregate and non-aggregate values"

Thanks but no luck!